# Facebook - hide content on website till "Like" button clicked

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, hidden

I'm using the wordpress plugin from http://www.sociable.es/facebook-wordpress-plugin-3-0/ on my blog, and I try to figure out, how they hide their download till I click the "Like" button on the post.

I tried:

```
<fb:fbml version="1.1">
<fb:visible-to-connection>HIDDEN CONTENT</fb:visible-to-connection>
</fb:fbml>
```

But it didn't work.

Is there a way with the Javascript SDK or any other solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You shouldn't make someone like something before they know what it is. That stuff on facebook is cancer.

Answer (score 1):

I think FBML has been done away with.  Found this bit of code:

```
$request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $load) = explode('.', $request, 2);

$fbData = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($load, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (!empty($fbData["page"]["liked"]))

{ ?>

You are a fan 

<?php } else { ?>

You are not a fan 

<?php }

//print_r($_REQUEST);

?>
```

However, the request variables are not being picked up by my iFrame.
Will update as i figure it out.

NB - would only works for the first time the user likes the page.  you'd have to then save the session variable or something.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ready solution for Wordpress:
[Like 2 Unlock for Wordpress](http://codecanyon.net/item/like-2-unlock-for-wordpress/2858703?ref=onepress)